Does there exist a continuous fuction $g(x)$ such that: $\int \frac{g(x)}{x} dx$ is finite at $x=0$ and $g(0)\ne0$?
Does there exist a continuous fuction $g(x)$ such that: $\int \frac{g(x)}{x} dx$ is finite at $x=0$ and $g(0)\ne0$?
Based on my calculations I am finding that for the integral condition to be true $g(x)$ must be proportional to $x$, which would cause $g(0)=0$. I am wondering if there is a 'special' function that meet both of these requirements.

If $g$ is continuous and $g(0) \neq 0$, then near $0$, $\dfrac{g(x)}{x} \sim \dfrac{g(0)}{x}$, so it is not integrable.

No, let's formally show it using the continuity definition.
If $g(x)$ is continious at $0$, then by definition of continuity $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ s.t. $|g(x) - g(0)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ s.t. $|x - 0| < \delta$. Let's pick $\epsilon = |g(0)|/2$. Then by triangle inequality for $|x| < \delta$ we get: $$|g(x)| = |(g(x) - g(0)) - (-g(0))| \geq \left||g(x) - g(0)| - |g(0)|\right| \geq ||g(0)| - |g(0)|/2| = |g(0)|/2.$$
Now without loss of generality assume that $g(0)>0$, then we get that $g(x) \geq \frac{g(0)}{2}$ for all $0 \leq x < \delta$.
Then $\int_0^\delta \frac{g(x)}{x} dx \geq \frac{g(0)}{2} \int_0^\delta \frac{dx}{x} = \infty$.
